# Stop adb screenrecord from java

Tags: java, android, selenium, selendroid

I'm using Selendroid in order to test my app.
At the beginning of each test I run adb shell screenrecord with the following function:

```
public static Process startScreenRecord(String fileName) throws IOException{
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\\sdk\\platform-tools\\ && adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/" + fileName);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    return p;
}
```

The recording is starting and everything looks OK. At the end of each test I try to stop the record via the following code:

```
public static void stopScreenRecord(Process p) throws IOException{
    p.destroy();
}
```

And in the test I use the following structure:

```
    Process p = CmdHelper.startScreenRecord("e1.mp4");
    //TestCode
    CmdHelper.stopScreenRecord(p);
```

The problem is that the video recording doesn't stop.
How can I stop the call recording at the end of each test?

Comment: You may want to use adb shell operations to find and kill the screenrecord process itself.  Beware android does not have a pkill or a killall, though it does now have a grep.

Comment: the problem is after killing the process the video is not saved. there is any 'clean' way to stop the process so the video will be saved?

Comment: @galvan           Can you please post the solution you came up with?  Did you get this to work? We are running into the same issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `adb shell screenrecord --help` documentation says that the two ways to terminate it are to set a time limit or to send it ctrl-C.

Assuming the time limit option doesn't work for you, the question would be how to send ctrl-C or its functional equivalent.  If you get an output stream connected to ADB's stdin and keep it open, you might be able to send a ctrl-c down that (or you might end up interrupting ADB and not the remote).

A different option, which seems to work is to use the kill command to send SIGINT (which is what ctrl-C typically does) rather than the SIGTERM signal which kill normally sends.  That should make the screenrecord process think you hit ctrl-c.

If you have found the process, id, the following seems to work and leave behind a video file:

```
adb shell kill -2 [pid number]
```

Where 2 is the usual number of SIGINT on Linux and thus Android.

Comment: How can I find the processID of screenrecord ?

Comment: Pipe the adb shell's `ps` into a `grep` for the process name, with grep running on whichever of the android device or your development machine  better supports it.  Maybe someday android will get a `pkill`

Comment: @ChrisStratton   Do you have a solution with the ps -ef | grep screenrecord or how were you doing this?

We are running into a similar issue.